# How do I reduce nested code when using .subscribe() in Angular rxjs?

Tags: angular, async-await, rxjs

I'm trying to write more readable code when using rxjs but I don't know how, the easiest way I can explain what I mean is using this pseudocode example that compares async/await and observable subscribe.

async/await pseudocode example:

```
let request1 = await doRequest();
let request2 = await doRequest2(request2);

doRequest(){
// make http call which returns json
}

doRequest2(request: json){
// check if request has certain value, if it does then do another request..
}
```

Observable pseudocode example:

```
 this.service.createRequest().subscribe(
    {
        next: (value)=>{
            // check if the value is in here, if it is, do another request
            this.service.createrequest2().subscribe({
                next: (value)=>{
                // we are now in processing the second request and the code is very nested
                               }
                    })
                }
                }
    )
```

Is there some way to reduce the nested code of observables?

I know that you can leave out the object from inside the `.subscribe()` and only use it like this `.subscribe(e=>{})` but it is still too nested for my taste.

Comment: This has been asked/answered many many many times already: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rxjs+nested+subscribe

Comment: Since the question is closed, I'm leaving [my solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-hp58mt?file=index.ts) which I developed for the past 20 minutes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll have to look at it in more detail. At first glance it looks more complicated than async/await though. I don't really understand what mergeMap() does. Atleast the name is confusing.